# Is there a way in signalr to remove a user from a list when that user disconnects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am making a little chat app with signalr, and when users click on Join the server adds that user to the `ConnectedUsers` list.

But how am i supposed to remove a specific user from the list and notify the other clients that the user disconnected?

**ChatHub.cs**

```
static List<User> ConnectedUsers = new List<User>();

public async Task Join(string name) {

            var id = Context.ConnectionId;
            ConnectedUsers.Add(new User {ID = id, Name = name});
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("update", "You have connected to the server.");
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("update", name + " has joined the server.");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("update-people", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConnectedUsers));
        }

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var _user = ConnectedUsers[Convert.ToInt32(Context.ConnectionId)];
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("test", _user);
            //ConnectedUsers.Remove();
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I expect that the user gets removed from the ConnectedUsers list and notify the other clients about the user disconnecting, but I can't use a await SendAsync in the override for OnDisconnectedAsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `OnDisconnectedAsync` function, find disconnected user in your `ConnectedUsers` (you have `ConnectionId` which earlier you assigned to the User ID) and remove that object from the list. After that boradcast updated users list.

Example:

```
public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        var itemToRemove = ConnectedUsers.Single(r => r.ID == Context.ConnectionId);
        ConnectedUsers.Remove(itemToRemove);

        Clients.Others.SendAsync("update", itemToRemove.Name + " has left the server.");
        Clients.All.SendAsync("update-people", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConnectedUsers));
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
```

Comment: It's giving me a error on the return:

Error CS1997 Since 'ChatHub.OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'? SignalRChat E:\dotNET\SignalRChat\SignalRChat\Hubs\ChatHub.cs 47 Active

Comment: tnx for the help